# Exclude files to avoid triggering Heroku CI

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

Currently my Heroku CI tests are triggered on all git push to `master` branch at Github.

Is it possible to avoid triggering CI tests if specific files are being pushed, such as `README.md`?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure heroku processes the `.slugignore` file for CI as there's an open issue now for ignoring it: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-ci/issues/39

The slugignore [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) say

> The .slugignore file causes files to be removed after you push code to Heroku and before the buildpack runs.

I don't use heroku ci so I wasn't able to test for sure. YMMV

Comment: I added .slugignore on top level in my github repo, with content "README.md". After I merged this to master, then changed README.md locally and pushed changes to remote, the last push again triggered Heroku CI. So it seems that Heroku CI is triggered anyways

Comment: I thought that _might_ happen. Unfortunately I don't see any documented way to skip builds, so this was just an educated guess. Other CI systems I've used (travis & gitlab) let you skip a build by including "skip ci" in the commit message body. I don't see anything like that in heroku's docs either though.